# Filter on search in android listView

Tags: android, android-listview, search-box

I am trying to search in list view in android. here is my code

```
        @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
       return new Filter(){

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                    constraint = constraint.toString();
                    List<FoodCell> founded = new ArrayList<FoodCell>();
                    for(FoodCell item: allItemFood){
                         if(item.cellText.toString().contains(constraint)){
                              founded.add(item);
                          }
                     }
                     result.values = founded;
                     result.count = founded.size();
                  }else 
                     result.count = 0;

                return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {             
            clear();
            if(results.count != 0){
                 for (FoodCell item : (List<FoodCell>) results.values) {
                       add(item);
                  }
             }                     
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        };
        }



    @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    //check if user deleted a character
    if(length > newText.length()){
        allItemFood = allItemFoodTmp;

    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.listfood,allItemFood);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    } else {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    }
    length = newText.length();
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

assume that we have the following items in list ,  aa,ab,ac 
when i enter text "aaz" as search query , it shows empty list which is true but when i delete character "z" from search query,the result remains empty which is false as a result expected.
how can i solve it ?

Comment: post the whole adapter

Comment: not useful,contains code for click action

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which widget you are using to take the search text input, if it is an EditView (considering which I am answering) then you should try adding a TextWatcher to it and then in the onTextChanged() method insert your search login which will execute it every time you add or remove a character inside the EditText.

Do let me know if you are using something else, and I will try to help accordingly. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Heres an example as well.   http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: i am using edit text and search on onTextChanged method but my problem is in deleting any character from search query,list is empty after it.i solved it by using temporary list to store values in it and re-assign in onTextChanged method

Comment: Good to hear that. :) Can you share the onTextChanged() method (only if you want to) and we can try and find if there's any other way around, you could avoid creating the additional list.